# Tick marks in a surface plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot a surface plot in matlab using the code below.

```matlab
f=figure('units','inches','Position',[0 0 5 10]);
ax=axes('Parent',f);
h=surf(X,Y,Z,'Parent',ax);
set(gca,'box','on');
```

The plot shows the tick labels but does not generate the tick marks inside the plot. This problem goes away when I replace the `surf` command with `contourf` in matlab. But I would like to know if there is a specific way to get the tick marks while using the `surf` option in matlab. Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

`surf` is actually a 3-dimensional object. If you view the plot from a 2D view (i.e. xy plane), then it's possible that the surface is covering the tick marks on the axes.

`contourf` is just a 2D object that is plotted beneath the tick marks.

Try replacing `surf` with `pcolor`, which should give the same result from a 2D view and not covering the tick marks.